# Initialize class' template (aggregate type) member with aggregate initializer but without extra parenthesis

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, c++14

Having this code:

```
struct Vec3 {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

template <typename T>
class myProperty {
public:
   myProperty(const T& initValue) : m_value{initValue} {}
private:
    T m_value;
};
```

When creating `myProperty` type object:

```
myProperty<int> ip{1};
myProperty<Vec3> vp1{{1, 2, 3}};
// myProperty<Vec3> vp2{1, 2, 3}; ERROR: myProperty doesn't have a matching constructor.
```

Is there an elegant way of making `vp2` initialization work?  Specializing `myProperty` for `Vec3` is an overkill.

Comment: Is making `myProperty` itself an aggregate an option? (I.e. remove the constructor and make `m_value` public.) Otherwise the only solution is see is a templated constructor, that forwards its arguments to the `T` constructor: `template <typename ...P> myProperty(P &&... p) : m_value(std::forward<P>(p)...) {}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, that [won't compile](https://onlinegdb.com/HyLLbHV6X).  To make it work, you'll have to put extra parentheses, like `m_value({std::forward<P>(p)...})`, that way `vp2` case will compile but `vp1` not.
And making `myProperty` an agregate is not an option.

Comment: Oops. It should be `: m_value{std::forward<P>(p)...}`, otherwise `myProperty<int> ip{1};` doesn't compile. *"vp2 case will compile but vp1 not"* Does it mean you want both `vp1` and  `vp2` to compile, not only `vp2`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, actually no, I don't want vp1 to compile :)  My bad, didn't test your suggestion thoroughly, assumed something like `vp4{myVec3Objet}` won't compile also, but it does, so this looks good :)  Would accept the answer if you post it.

Comment: Turns out it breaks copy-construction (because it's a better match than `myProperty(const myProperty &)` if the parameter is non-const). I'll post an answer if I figure out how to fix that in a neat way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a variadic template constructor:

```
template <typename ...P> myProperty(P &&... p) : m_value{std::forward<P>(p)...} {}
```

It makes `myProperty<Vec3> vp2{1, 2, 3};` compile.

Also it stops `myProperty<Vec3> vp1{{1, 2, 3}};` from compiling (which seems to match your intentions).

The problem with this option is that it prevents copy construction from working propertly.
(If the parameter is a non-const `myProperty<T>` lvalue, then this variadic constructor is a better match than `myProperty(const myProperty &)`.)

This can be solved with SFINAE:

**C++17 with `<experimental/type_traits>`:**

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename ...P> using list_constructible = decltype(T{std::declval<P>()...});

// ...

template
<
    typename ...P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::experimental::is_detected_v<list_constructible, T, P...>>
>
myProperty(P &&... p) : m_value{std::forward<P>(p)...} {}
```

**C++14:**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename...> using void_t = void;
template <typename DummyVoid, template <typename...> class A, typename ...B> struct is_detected : std::false_type {};
template <template <typename...> class A, typename ...B> struct is_detected<void_t<A<B...>>, A, B...> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T, typename ...P> using list_constructible = decltype(T{std::declval<P>()...});

// ...

template
<
    typename ...P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<is_detected<void, list_constructible, T, P...>::value>
>
myProperty(P &&... p) : m_value{std::forward<P>(p)...} {}
```

Comment: Yet only an upvote, to have some time to experiment with this solution and also keep the question open for alternative solutions.